# Django Rest: DELETE for /resource/

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Can anyone please shine some light on how best to set up a route for `DELETE` at a resource?

Typically, if I use a `GenericAPIView`, I can inherit the `mixins.DestroyModelMixin`.

**example**:

I could then have end point `/resource/{id}` for `DELETE`

**Q**: How would I have an endpoint for `/resource/` for `DELETE`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Like you mentioned, simply add the `DestroyModelMixin` to your detail view. Then delete resources with requests like:

```
curl -X DELETE "http://127.0.0.1:8000/resouce/1/"
```

More info about the `DELETE` http method [here](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html).

> DELETE is pretty easy to understand. It is used to **delete** a
>   resource identified by a URI.
>
> On successful deletion, return HTTP status 200 (OK) along with a
>   response body, perhaps the representation of the deleted item (often
>   demands too much bandwidth), or a wrapped response (see Return Values
>   below). Either that or return HTTP status 204 (NO CONTENT) with no
>   response body. In other words, a 204 status with no body, or the
>   JSEND-style response and HTTP status 200 are the recommended
>   responses.
>
> HTTP-spec-wise, DELETE operations are idempotent. If you DELETE a
>   resource, it's removed. Repeatedly calling DELETE on that resource
>   ends up the same: the resource is gone. If calling DELETE say,
>   decrements a counter (within the resource), the DELETE call is no
>   longer idempotent. As mentioned previously, usage statistics and
>   measurements may be updated while still considering the service
>   idempotent as long as no resource data is changed. Using POST for
>   non-idempotent resource requests is recommended.
>
> There is a caveat about DELETE idempotence, however. Calling DELETE on
>   a resource a second time will often return a 404 (NOT FOUND) since it
>   was already removed and therefore is no longer findable. This, by some
>   opinions, makes DELETE operations no longer idempotent, however, the
>   end-state of the resource is the same. Returning a 404 is acceptable
>   and communicates accurately the status of the call.
>
> Examples:
>
> - DELETE http://www.example.com/customers/12345
> - DELETE http://www.example.com/customers/12345/orders
> - DELETE http://www.example.com/bucket/sample

Comment: What I want to do is to have an endpoint for:

* DELETE http://abc.xyz/customer/

not a particular resource with an {id}

Answer (score 0):

Found out the way to do this.  Add a delete() method at the ViewSet class, eg

```
Class MyViewSet(GenericViewSet):
    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      ...
```

Then I could do:

```
curl -X DELETE "http://127.0.0.1:8000/resouce/"
```